# How to remove space above the <UL> Tag in Outlook?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

Here is my code

```
<span>Services</span>
<ul style="Margin-top: 0px !important; Padding-top: 0px;">
  <li> Services 1 </li>
  <li> Services 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS which I am using to remove Margin Top in OUTLOOK

```
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style>
        ul {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
      }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Even adding all these I can not remove space above the UL tag. Please help.

Comment: What space you talking about? mean what is your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

On Outlook desktop versions there is a margin on the list items `<li>`

But for cross-email-client support you need `margin-top:0` on the `<ul>` as well, like so:

```
<span>Services</span>
<ul style="margin-top: 0;">
  <li style="margin-top: 0; "> Services 1 </li>
  <li> Services 2</li>
</ul>
```

No extra CSS is necessary.